Now that Zipline is no longer being maintained. What back testing alternative would you recommend
I am building a self hosted stack so there has been a lot of trial and error in order to head off a headache or two I thought I would reach out for a group opinion. I am evaluating back testers and I have had a great experience with zipline previously. Now that it is no longer being maintained (but has many branches I am not sure which to choose or if it would be a good fit for what I need.)
This would be for an event driven liquidity // volatility arbitrage strategy avg. hold time between 15 min and 3 hr. I use TimescaleDB ontop of PostgreSQL for my market data storage. I use a mix of PostgreSQL and MongoDB for my alt datasets (I do need to consolidate).
I was curious if anyone had any strong opinions on opensource backtesters for this use case.
Chears,
